# Rewrite request from POST to GET with nginx

Tags: nginx, http, rewrite

I've got a backend server that, for various reasons, only processes GET requests. This server is located behind nginx proxy (i.e. all access is done to nginx, which proxies it to the backend with `proxy_pass`). Is it possible to make nginx rewrite POST requests into GET requests, i.e. so that `POST /foo` with body content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and body `foo=bar` would be proxied to `GET /foo?foo=bar`?

Comment: The [`proxy_method`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_method) maybe?

Comment: proxy_method does not carry over the foo=bar part, unfortunately.

Comment: I *strongly* suspect that you're going to end up going down to lua; you'll need to handle the case where the URL has query params as well, and merge them. I feel for you, having to deal with a backend device this horribly broken, and presumably clients you can't fix to not send POSTs.  I'm glad I don't have your job.

Comment: 301/302 HTTP redirect may help but it is highly not recommended, try some kind of middleware that turns POST into GET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The small example is working for me with nginx 1.10.x at ubuntu 16.04 with nginx-extras (contains lua). It doesnt respect query arguments from the request, to merge them with the post body.

```
server {
    ...
    server_name ...;

    client_max_body_size 4k; # prevent too long post bodies

    location / {
            if ($request_method = POST ) {
                access_by_lua '
                        ngx.req.read_body()
                        local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
                        ngx.req.set_uri_args(data)
                ';                
            }

            proxy_pass http://yourupstreamdestination;
            proxy_method GET;                    # change method
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params.inc; # include some params
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51139521/1707015 (not exactly to the question, but maybe helpful).

Answer (score 1):

Improving [Falk Nisius's original answer](https://serverfault.com/a/836149/384990), but without the caveat:

> It doesnt respect query arguments from the request, to merge them with the post body.

You can switch to using `get_post_args` instead of `get_body_data`, which returns a table instead of a string.

`set_uri_args` can take a string OR a table, so in this case, you can combine it with the table from `get_post_args`.

Combining the 2 tables will get you all arguments, as per example:

```
server {
    ...
    server_name ...;

    client_max_body_size 4k; # prevent too long post bodies

    location / {
            if ($request_method = POST ) {
                access_by_lua '
                        ngx.req.read_body()

                        local post_data = ngx.req.get_post_args()
                        local get_data = ngx.req.get_uri_args()
                        for k,v in pairs(get_data) do post_data[k] = v end

                        ngx.req.set_uri_args(post_data)
                ';                
            }

            proxy_pass http://yourupstreamdestination;
            proxy_method GET;                    # change method
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params.inc; # include some params
    }
}
```